# python check if a dictionary key has a certain value

Tags: python

I have a function that returns data in such structure:

```
dict1 = [{'status':u'received'}]
dict2 = [{'status': u'pending'}]
```

I want to check the status and returns some value according to the status.
Not that it makes any sense to myself but I tried doing this :

```
if 'received' in dict1.values('status'):
     #do something
```

and the result was as expected, "it didn't work". It was just a panic try.

Comment: Your `dict1` is actually a list containing a single dict. Is that how it should be? Could it contain multiple dicts?

Comment: `dict1` and `dict2` are not dictionaries. They're lists. Lists don't have a `values' method so this will not work.

Comment: Things would be simpler if you used `dict1 = {'status': u'received'}` as then the code `if 'received' in dict1.get('status',''):` will do what is expected.

Comment: yes, but how do i check them values?? I simply want to check if the status are 'pending' or 'received' or 'rejected'. And it doesnot contains multiple dicts, but the function returns multiples lists like those of dict1, dict2, dict3, ...

Comment: @Paul yes, but the function returns an object like above, which is why you can call `dict1[0]` to eliminate that (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is having confusing names, I think. `dict1` and `dict2` are, in fact, not dictionaries, but lists containing a dict. That may not be what you want. In case it is, and if I understand what you want,

```
if any(element['status'] == 'received' for element in dict1):
    # do something
```

(It is not clear what you want to return in case of multi-element lists, like `[{'status':u'received'}, {'status':u'pending'}]`, or if you even can get something like that; you might need to modify depending on your answer)

Answer (score 2):

Your "dictionaries" are actually lists. Thus, when you try to call `dict1.values()`, you are calling `.values` on a list. Try calling `dict1[0].values()` instead:

```
>>> dict1 = [{'status':u'received'}]
>>> dict2 = [{'status': u'pending'}]
>>> 'received' in dict1[0].values()
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

To test if any dictionary in the list `dict1` has a value `received`:

```
>>> dict1 = [{'status':u'received'}]
>>> any(u'received' in d.values() for d in dict1)
True
```

To check more specifically if any dictionary in the list `dict1` has a status of received:

```
>>> any(u'received' == d.get('status') for d in dict1)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

since you have a list containing dictionaries,
you could try

```
for element in dict1:
    if 'received' in element.values():
        #then do something
```